# Windowservice error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-services

I have solution which contain so many projects and windowservices. I modified coding on the application side of windowservice,after that i copied the exe 
regarding that service(F:\Components\Console\Bin\service.exe) 
in to the installation path(C:\Program Files\syscon\ Monitor\service.exe) after 
stopping windowservice from the 'services.msc'.Now i am getting the value on service while debugging which is not getting previously.But now when i start the
 service from 'services.msc' i am getting this error ***"Could not start the operational sentinel windows resource monitor service on local computer.Error 1053:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"***
Can any tell me a solution for this

Comment: but i installed new version of framework also,,but it still existing

Answer (score 2):

We create many services during our work and one method for debugging I've found very useful is the following:

Make your service a "dual application" that can run as a service or as a normal Windows Forms application, controlled by some command line parameter. I pass "/gui" to my services.

In `void Main(string[] args)` I check for the parameter:

If it is missing, I execute the code to instantiate the service (the code generated by Visual Studio).

If it is there, I run code to create a normal Windows Forms application, where the main form instantiates the service and calls `OnStart` and `OnStop` accordingly (you'll have to create wrapper methods due to visibility of `OnStart` and `OnStop`).

Of course you have to add the references to the Windows Forms assemblies manually and add code like `Application.Run(...)` yourself, but debugging capabilities are greatly improved without going through the hassle of the "Stop Service, Copy File, Start Service, Fail"-routine.

Most likely, there's a bug in your `OnStart` code which makes the instance drop out of that routine and the service manager keeps waiting.

**EDIT**
Here's a code sample for you of the way I create the service/gui depending on the parameter:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 0 && args[0].Equals("/gui"))
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new FrmGui());
    }
    else
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new SampleService() };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```